# Anova Test- Separate Groups with Two Factor Comparison

Tags: r, anova

Good morning, 
I am trying to run some ANOVA tests on my dataset (using R) and I keep getting errors.  I am trying to compare the average percentage of correct responses, as a factor of what "group" the subjects were in and what session/day it was.  However, I have two separate conditions that I need to analyze separately.

So essentially, I need to compare PctCorrect in Condition 1, between groups and sessions and then do the same thing for condition 2.

I attempted using this code:

```
aov(ext$Pct.Correct[ext$Condition=="NC-EXT"]~ext$Group*ext$Session, data=ext)
```

and I got the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = ext$Pct.Correct[ext$Condition
>   == : variable lengths differ (found for 'ext$Group')

I ran this code to make sure that all of my values were even:

```
mytable <- table(ext$Session, ext$Group, ext$Condition) 
ftable(mytable)
```

And they were all the same value (which was to be expected), so I am not sure what's wrong.

I am very new to R so it's entirely possible that I am doing this completely wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering the left side of the equation and not filtering the right side, thus the "variable length error".

You could try filter your dataframe in the `data=` option like this:

```
aov(Pct.Correct ~ Group* Session, data=ext[ext$Condition=="NC-EXT",])
```